# ofstream doesn't create file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to output every element of my array into a .txt file but for some reason it doesn't even create the file. I have both a cmd output and file output in my display method which is called from the main. The cmd output works perfectly but when i use ofstream to try and create a file and output the array's element to it, i don't see any text file created.

```
ofstream ofs("TEST.txt");

if(!ofs)
    cout << "cannot use" << endl;
else
{
    for(int a=0; a < 12; a++)
    {
        for(int b=0; b < 12; b++)
        {

            cout << RandomArray[a][b] << "\t";
            ofs << RandomArray[a][b];
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }

}

ofs.close();
```

Comment: Do you see the `cannot use` text or you just don't see the file? And when and where do you check for the file?

Comment: pay attention that your `ofs.close()` is also called when the stream is not opened.

Comment: Did you look in the same directory as your porgram/executable resides for the file?

Comment: Kiril Kirov
It isn't created at all. I go to the start button and do a search there for "programs and files". In Java that's how i find the files that are created by my program.

qdii, thanks, i'll edit that.

Comment: @qdii: Calling `close()` is never necessary even if the stream *was* opened successfully, because `~basic_filebuf()` calls `close()`.

Comment: What is the cmd output you mention?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but I would try writing at least one newline in the created file. I know that it doesn't matter on UNIXes but I'm always suspicious of anything out of convention on Windows (which isn't based on fact but ignorance, though). The program as above looks OK (assuming this is the entire `main()` following the obligatory `#include <fstream>` and `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`). The only unusual bit is the absence of a newline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#define SYSERROR()  GetLastError()
#else
#include <errno.h>
#define SYSERROR()  errno
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ofstream of("TEXT.TXT");
    if(of.is_open())
    {
        of<<"Some text here"<<std::endl;
        of.flush();
        of.close();
        std::cout<<"wrote the file successfully!"<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr<<"Failed to open file : "<<SYSERROR()<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The win32 GetLastError() #define isn't tested, as I don't have a windows box handy. The errno bit works. this will at least tell you what the error is if the file open fails

Comment: yeah... i don't have access to windows, so haven't tested on windows.. but the GetLastError() should work to show the error on windows... just putting a caveat emptor :D

Comment: Yes, `GetLastError()` does work on Windows. Tested using Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.20348.0.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is okay, it should work so long as `ofstream` can be created. I think that you are not looking in the right directory.

Comment: You know what, you are correct! I just did a search through my entire computer and it showed up. So silly... sorry and thank you!